# Why specifiy "exp()" when using log-link in STAN?

Tags: regression, bayesian, poisson, stan, gamma

I am using STAN to use a gamma-poisson regression to account for over-dispersion in a dataset, in an assignment. I have looked at the solutions to how to make the model in STAN, which is shown below:

```
model{
    vector[N] lambda;
    scale ~ cauchy( 0 , 1 );
    bf ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    a ~ normal( 0 , 10 );
    for ( i in 1:N ) {
        lambda[i] = a + bf * fmnnty[i];
        lambda[i] = exp(lambda[i]);
    }
    deaths ~ neg_binomial_2( lambda , scale );
}
```

The solution specify to use the log-link function to limit the parameter lambda to positive values. This makes sense. However, I don't understand why the STAN-code uses exp() as a link-function. Why is it that the exp() is appropriate to specify a log-link function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log-link is employed by exponentiating the lambda. The 'log' component means that you are modeling the log of the mean value (`mu`):

`log(mu) = lambda`

Which you can rewrite as:

`mu = exp(lambda)`

Comment: That is correct, although the OP's code would be better off using `deaths ~ neg_binomial_2_log(lambda, scale);` as the last line and not exponentiating `lambda` inside the `for` loop. Exponentiating runs the risk of numerical overflow or loss of precision in evaluating the log-likelihood. Even better would be to use `neg_binomial_2_log_glm` function, which takes a matrix of predictors as one of its arguments, and evaluates the derivatives much faster.